# Dismissing GameScene in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm making a simple pong game with Swift in `SpriteKit`.

I'm new to `SpriteKit` so I can't yet solve my problem. I have menu `UIViewController`, `GameViewController` and a `UINavigationController` to switch between them:

[image: Screenshot]

Everything is OK but when one of the players gets 10 points I want to go back to the menu. I searched but nothing works for me.

GameScene code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

var currentgame = gameType.deafoult //game type enumeration

class GameScene: SKScene {

//If game start enumeration
enum gamestart {
    case yes, no
}

//Variables
var start = gamestart.no
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
var main = SKSpriteNode()
var tplab = SKLabelNode()
var btlab = SKLabelNode()
var startlab = SKLabelNode()



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     for touch in touches {
        let position = touch.location(in: self)
        if position.y > 0 && currentgame == .player2 {
            enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: position.x, duration: 0.2))
        }
        if position.y < 0 {
            main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: position.x, duration: 0.2))
        }
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let position = touch.location(in: self)
        if position.y > 0 && currentgame == .player2 {
            enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: position.x, duration: 0.2))
        }
        if position.y < 0 {
            main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: position.x, duration: 0.2))
        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if start == .no {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        var minusx = touchLocation.x - startlab.position.x
        var minusy = touchLocation.y - startlab.position.y
        if minusx < 0 {
            minusx = -minusx
        }
        //checking if player click on label to start game
        if minusy < 0 {
            minusy = -minusy
        }
        if minusx > 0 && minusx < 16 && minusy > 0 && minusy < 16 {
            start = .yes
            startlab.alpha = 0
            startgame()
        }
        print(touchLocation)
        print(startlab.position)
    }
}
var score = [0,0] //scores

//start game fun
func startgame() {
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:10, dy: 10))
    score = [0,0]
    btlab.text = String(score[0])
    tplab.text = String(score[1])
}


func addscore(WhoWin: SKNode) {

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    if WhoWin == main {
        score[0] += 1
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))
    }else {
        score[1] += 1
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10, dy: -10))
    }
btlab.text = String(score[0])
tplab.text = String(score[1])

    if score[0] == 10 {
    print("test 1")
    //go to menu
    }else if score[1] == 10 {
    print("test 1")
    //go to menu
    }
}


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    startlab = self.childNode(withName: "labstart") as! SKLabelNode
    startlab.position.x = ((self.view?.frame.width)!/2) - 50
    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy.position.y = ((self.view?.frame.height)!/2) - 50
    tplab = self.childNode(withName: "labeltop") as! SKLabelNode
    btlab = self.childNode(withName: "labelbt") as! SKLabelNode
    main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode
    main.position.y = -(((self.view?.frame.height)!/2) - 50)
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1
    self.physicsBody = border
    start = .no
}
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


        switch currentgame {
        case .easy:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.8))
        case .medium:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.5))
        case .hard:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.3))
        case .endless:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.1))
        default: break

        }



        if ball.position.y <= main.position.y - 30 {
            addscore(WhoWin: enemy)
        }else if ball.position.y >= enemy.position.y + 30 {
            addscore(WhoWin: main)
        }


}
}
```

My ViewController with menu code:

```
    import UIKit

enum gameType {
case player2, hard, easy, medium, endless, deafoult
}


class MyVCViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func Player2(_ sender: Any) {
gotogame(game: .player2)
}
@IBAction func EasyMode(_ sender: Any) {
gotogame(game: .easy)
}
@IBAction func Mediummode(_ sender: Any) {
gotogame(game: .medium)
}
@IBAction func hardmode(_ sender: Any) {
gotogame(game: .hard)
}
@IBAction func endlessmode(_ sender: Any) {
gotogame(game: .endless)
}

func gotogame(game: gameType) {
    let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController

    currentgame = game
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)
}
}
```

And my GameViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit




class GameViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            scene.size = view.bounds.size

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

How can I go back to the menu when one of the players get 10 points?

Comment: You could implement a protocol/delegate to call a game ViewController method from the game scene as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41891516/1894067)

Comment: i implement that and it works but I don't know how to diss miss GameScene in function "callMethod"

Comment: You could dismiss your scene by `presentScene:nil`, then launch `callMethod`

Comment: It works thank you very much :)